# Article for programming data types

Tags: articles, programming

I'm writing documentation for my data analysis framework, and there are classes Histogram and Graph. I document a function that transforms one Histogram to one Graph as

> Transform a Histogram to Graph

and I'm not sure whether it is better to use "Graph" with or without an article here.

I searched for examples with 'int' and 'float', and get contradicting results:

> To convert [an integer to a float](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33944290/952234)

> how to convert [int to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33944111)

I understand they might be non-native speakers.

When I Google, it suggests

> People also ask
> How do you convert an int to a float?

I think that article usage may depend on the frequency of the word's usage (so for int and float it might be different than for my types; but if I assume that users are familiar with my framework?..).

I understand that my question of the programming types might be very narrow, but would be glad for a comprehensive general case it is probably part of. Are articles in programming a local jargon; should I use the "programming convention" (if that exists), or the "grammatically correct" variant (if that exists)?

P.S. Feel free to correct articles in my question, I'm not a native speaker :)

Comment: I found a similar question with the answer "in programming 'String class' could be describing a general programming class called 'String' while 'class String' a specific class called 'String'. So 'objects of the String class' is not necessarily the same as 'objects of class String'." https://english.stackexchange.com/a/469486/116650 - but I don't completely understand that. Maybe it should be "objects of the string class"? Maybe s.o. else could explain it better just for types (not as that large question I link).

Comment: It's odd that your expression *Transform a Histogram to Graph* uses *a* for *Histogram* but not for *Graph*.  Use it for both or neither - then the problem goes away?  See how the other examples you show us are consistent in their use or non-use of the article (or whatever you want to call *a* and *the*).

Comment: Are you titling a subroutine? Consider that internal program documentation (called remarks or comments) speaks only to developers. The telegraph style of *histogram to graph* fits the audience. External documentation speaks to both technical and nontechnical readers. The traditional style of *Transform a histogram to a graph* fits that more general audience.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark This may sound stupid, but I feel like there is a slight difference between "any histogram" and "the graph". This is like "I saw a squirrel, and the beast was red". However, if you are sure, then I can fix that.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - this is the official documentation (for everyone). I write a library, so this is not for internal usage, but for users of the framework. In fact I already published that, so it looks like this: https://lena.readthedocs.io/en/latest/structures.html#lena.structures.elements.HistToGraph .

Comment: I wouldn't leave "Transform a Histogram to Graph" but change it to "Transform a Histogram to *a* Graph."

Comment: @YosefBaskin thank for the hint. I appreciate that you are a "technical writer", as you put it in your resume here. However, I find usages of mixed articles. For example, Bob Carpenter (sounds like a native speaker) writes "to convert a vector to array" on https://groups.google.com/g/stan-users/c/4UuGWLqU8tQ/m/_v9u9GGDAAAJ . I would gladly accept an answer about style (or grammar) here, if that is founded and a bit more detailed.

Comment: I fixed my documentation. I chose "a histogram to a graph" (initially I wanted to use "histograms to graphs", but this failed because of markup for class names). Thanks to everyone - maybe I should had posted on English Language Learners instead of here, but it seems I found that site only now! I didn't think these were different ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been programming for over 40 years, and I think both styles are common and idiomatic. But as mentioned in several comments, you should be self-consistent within the sentence, so either

> Transform Histogram to Graph

or

> Transform a Histogram to a Graph

I believe the reason that it's acceptable without the article is because a type/class name can be used as a collective noun referring to objects of the given type in general. However, I think the form without articles is more often used in synopses, which tend to be terse, rather than the main text of the documentation; it's similar to the way newspaper headlines leave out noise words.

You could also write

> Transforms Histograms to Graphs

but this tends to be avoided because the type name is a specific term in the programming language, and adding the plural suffix results in something that doesn't match that term. It could be distinguished using typography, e.g. `Histogram`s, but this looks weird and can also be lost as the documentation is converted to different formats.

Comment: Thank you, Barmar! I think this answers my question, and I accept this. I'll change my docs when I return to them. It's interesting that both forms are possible (and many thanks for the grammatical explanation for that!), but not together! "You should be self-consistent within the sentence" - I'll pay attention to that if I find this rule in grammar books next time!